# How to plot a state vector in Bloch sphere on Qutip?

Tags: python, quantum-computing, qutip

Very simple. I define a Qutip state object

```
import qutip as qt
import numpy as np

state = qt.Qobj(1/2*np.array([np.sqrt(3),-1])) # This is my quantum state vector (normalized)
```

What I want is plotting this state in Bloch sphere, but if I just do:

```
b = qt.Bloch()
b.add_vectors(state)
b.show()
```

It gives me an error

> IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

I suppose this is due to the interpretation of my state as a normal 3D vector. So, there exists a simple way to go with this kind of plot?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change `b.add_vectors(state)` by `b.add_states(state)` because you're adding a state (a `Qobj` object) not a vector (coordinates on the x, y and z axis as a sequence).

See the [the qutip documentation](http://qutip.org/docs/4.1/apidoc/classes.html#qutip.bloch.Bloch.add_states) for more